# how to create a grid using canvas in android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, canvas, grid

I am trying to create a 10x10 grid in android studio that will display in the center of the screen, i am trying to use a for loop to do this but cant get it right. Does anyone know how to do this, ive been looking on google and there are no examples or guides on how to do it. my code is below.

```
public class Draw extends View {
Paint red = new Paint();
Paint green = new Paint();
float startX;
float stopX;
float startY;
float stopY;
int rectSide = 1000;

public Draw(Context context) {
    super(context);
    red.setColor(Color.RED);
    green.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    red.setStrokeWidth(8);
    green.setStrokeWidth(8);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = canvas.getHeight();

    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {

        startX = width / 2 - rectSide / 2;
        startY = i*100;
        stopX = width / 2 + rectSide / 2;
        stopY = i*100;

        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, red);

    }

    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {

        startX = i*100;
        startY = height / 2 - rectSide / 2;
        stopX = i*100;
        stopY = height / 2 + rectSide / 2;

        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, red);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: startX = width / 2 - rectSide / 2; It makes no sense to put such statements IN the loop as it has nothing to do with i. Put them before the loop. It will make code clearer. After that rethink how you would draw horizontal lines in a loop. And then how vertical lines in a loop.

Comment: You did not tell what goes wrong now. What kind of pattern is produced by the first for loop?

Comment: Ive tried lots of different for loops, i cant get it to display 10x10 in the middle of the screen. I know how to make a grid layout, i just dont know how to make it so it will be a 10x10 grid in the center no matter what screen size, that is why i started messing with canvas.getHeight and width.

Comment: You should have told that right away of course. And still you should take all those statements out of the loops to begin with. Then tell where you want your grid if the screen is 1024 wide for example.

Comment: float startX;
float stopX;
float startY;
float stopY; You should make them local variables of onDraw. Only declare variables where you use them.

Comment: for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)  Dont make it yourself difficult. Change that to  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Use int maxlines =10; and for (int i = 0; i < maxlines; i++) . You will need maxlines for start calculations too.